# Continue remote bash script

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I'm only an apprentice in my first year and this is my first post, so please bear with me.

First of all: We use Raspberry Pi's with stretch distribution.

With every update we roll out we have to do release tests. Normally one has to execute certain commands manually and remotely on the Pi's via ssh and compare the outcome with what it should be, if the new release works. I'm currently working on automating this process with a bash script which works fine so far.

However, at various points we have to create certain flagfiles that initiate certain processes and reboot the Pi afterwards so it detects the flagfiles and executes the processes. The problem is that rebooting of course ends my script.

Now I know that you can just write a cronjob that executes a script @reboot or write a function in your script that checks for states and then executes the "after-reboot" part of your script, but these solutions all require the scripts being locally on the Pi, if I understood them correctly. But I have to run my scipts remotely via ssh from my office PC with sourcing my config and handover parameters and such.

This is what I run in my start script:

```
#!/bin/bash
CONFIG=/home/user/Schreibtisch/config.sh
source $CONFIG
echo "Release AutoTest V0.7 on $DEVICE_ID"
echo "Make sure an external WLAN chip is plugged in"
read -p "Press ENTER to start"
ssh root@$DEVICE_IP "bash -s" -- < /home/user/Schreibtisch/auto_test.sh "$PMD" "$BTDMD" "$AND TEN MORE PARAMETERS..."

exit 0
```

The "auto_test.sh" is the actual script that runs on the Pi.

So is there a way to "tell" my local script is has to wait for the reboot and then start the next portion or anything? Or just being able to go back to my "auto_start.sh" for which I could write an after reboot part and giving the Pi a second script after a sleep of 40 or something. (Or better yet a detection when the Pi is running again, but that is a thing I can work on my self.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing the script on the Raspberry Pi you can ping the Pi until it responds:

```
#!/bin/bash
CONFIG=/home/user/Schreibtisch/config.sh
source $CONFIG
echo "Release AutoTest V0.7 on $DEVICE_ID"
echo "Make sure an external WLAN chip is plugged in"
read -p "Press ENTER to start"
ssh root@$DEVICE_IP "bash -s" -- < /home/user/Schreibtisch/auto_test.sh "$PMD" "$BTDMD" "$AND TEN MORE PARAMETERS..."
while ! ping -c 1 -n -w 1 DEVICE_IP &> /dev/null; do :; done

# Execute whatever you want after the reboot

exit 0
```